# Simple Scatter for Geometry Nodes breaks when using a Collection

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have an extremely simple geometry nodes scatter setup.

The issue I am having is that, when moving from a single object for the scatter to a collection, the scatter objects do not render on the object as expected.

Here is the setup with a single object on the scatter:

[image]

Here is the exact same object with the collection used as the render objects.

[image]

Here is my simple node setup. To swap between the two, I took the corresponding geometry inputs and plugged that into `Instance` in `Instance on Points`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check "reset children" on your collection info node and check "pick instance" on "instance on points" node.

Without this check Blender does take the position of each instance into account.

Comment: Only when applying both "reset children" and "Separate children" do the objects distribute on the points. However, the issue now is that all the items in my collection stack on top of the same point - so for every point, I have three items on it

Comment: To solve the three points issue, I ticked `Pick Instance` so that blender, instead of rendering all three items, would `pick` one out of the three to render

Comment: ok, updated my answer